# Gremlin Javascript order by function

Tags: node.js, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I use gremlin-javascript (in aws Neptune) to traverse the remote graph and get a list of vertex. I want order the vertex by their `createdAt` date property. But since I have multiple order().by(), I want to group them by week.

```js
const gremlin = require('gremlin')
const moment = require('moment')

const { Graph } = gremlin.structure
const { DriverRemoteConnection } = gremlin.driver
const __ = gremlin.process.statics
const { order } = gremlin.process


const getWeek = date => parseInt(moment(date).format('YYYYWW'), 10)

const graph = new Graph()
const dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(endpointNeptune)
const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc)

g.V().order().by(getWeek(__.values('createdAt')), order.decr)
```

But this throw an error: `"Could not locate method: NeptuneGraphTraversal.by([202029, decr])"`

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a literal value where a property key name is expected.

Rather than do the order first have you considered something like `group().by('createdAt').order(local).by(keys,desc)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Copying my earlier comment to an answer:

The `by` modulator is expecting a key name not a literal value. Something like

```
g.V().group().by('createdAt').order(local).by(keys,desc)
```

or perhaps depending on your data model

```
g.V().order().by('createdAt', order.desc)
```